# Class is not defined in implementation file

Tags: c++

When I try to compile my implementation file using `g++ -c Sorting_Functions.cpp`, I get this message

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'IntSort'

### IntSort.h

```cpp
#ifndef INTSORT_H_

#define INTSORT_H_

#include "Sorting_Functions.cpp"

class IntSort 
{

public:

    IntSort();
    void print();


private:

    int arr[5];
    int len;
};

#endif
```

### Sorting_Functions.cpp

```cpp
#include "IntSort.h"

using namespace std;

IntSort::IntSort()
{

    arr[0] = 7;

    arr[1] = 3;

    arr[2] = 2;

    arr[3] = 6;

    arr[4] = 4;

    len = 5;
}

// prints the lists to the user

void IntSort::print()
{

    cout << "{ ";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "}";
}
```

Comment: Don’t include `.cpp` files: `#include "Sorting_Functions.cpp"` doesn’t work.

Comment: Because of above, you wound up with a circular dependency. IntSort.h needs Sorting_Functions.cpp and Sorting_Functions.cpp needs IntSort.h, but since IntSort.h has already been included the include guard prevents it from being included again. This leaves Sorting_Functions.cpp stuck because `class IntSort` hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: And because of the recursive inclusion (and the fact the `#ifdef` skip the file on the second loop), you will end up that the compiler will see `IntSort::IntSort()` before it see `class IntSort...`

Comment: Here's a good answer that shows exactly what happens when the compiler (preprocessor, really) starts trying to interpret the files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/628079/4581301

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the inclusion of a source file (.cpp or .cc). Only header files (.h) should be included, and all source files should be compiled. Remove the source file `#include` and the code should be fine.

The "undeclared identifier" error is caused by `Sorting_Functions.cpp` including `IntSort.h` which in turn includes `Sorting_Functions.cpp` - the compiler will first see the type `IntSort` being used, which at this point has not yet been declared (which happens in `IntSort.h` after the `#include`).

Comment: Note: Once the .cpp file is no longer included, you may have to tell your build tools to compile and link it. Many build tools are smart enough to recognize a cpp file and automatically compile and link it, and this is where you usually get in trouble: everything in the cpp file winds up multiply defined. It's in the cpp file and also in every file that included the cpp file.